# MongoDB db.collection.findOne() utility

Tags: mongodb

i'm a mongoDB newbie and i'm wondering what is the utility of the `findOne` method. I mean, i can see the utility for the `justOne` attribute for the remove method, that avoid dangerous requests injection that could delete lot of your data, but what is the utility of `findOne`?

If someone with bad intention would inject request through my `find` method he could see all the data? Couldn't he do the same through the `findOne` method by running lot of injected queries?

Why would i need to get just a document from a query that matches with more documents? and why would i need to get the first of them in the disk order? 
if i need a precise document i query it univocally.

I apologies for the absurdities i have probably wrote, but im trying to understand

Comment: Typically you use `findOne` with an Object ID that needs to be converted to a BSON object. I use it to find a user.

Comment: mmmm and why would I convert an _id to a BSON object? security purpose? if i need to query a specific user i query it by username if i know it, or by Object_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, it's a handy shortcut for `find({ ... }).limit(1).pretty()[0]` in the mongo shell.

Note the `[0]`: `findOne` returns a *document* rather than a *cursor*.

Why use it? Let's say you want to find a document by `_id` (can only have a single result), it saves you from a bit of typing.

> Why would i need to get just a document from a query that matches with more documents? and why would i need to get the first of them in the disk order? if i need a precise document i query it univocally.

Well, if you know what you're looking for. Let's say you want to have the most recent error from a log, then sth. like `findOne({"severity" : "error"})` would be exactly what you need.